# Getting error in calculating hog features of multiple images and writing it in a text file

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to calculate HOG feature vectors of multiple images and writing in a text file column wise .But I ma getting this error:
    np.savetxt('hog.txt',out)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 132
0, in savetxt
    "Expected 1D or 2D array, got %dD array instead" % X.ndim)
ValueError: Expected 1D or 2D array, got 3D array instead

Here is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
winSize = (64,64)
blockSize = (16,16)
blockStride = (8,8)
cellSize = (8,8)
nbins = 9
derivAperture = 1
winSigma = 4.
histogramNormType = 0
L2HysThreshold = 2.0000000000000001e-01
gammaCorrection = 0
nlevels = 64
hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor(winSize,blockSize,blockStride,cellSize,nbins,derivAperture,winSigma,
                        histogramNormType,L2HysThreshold,gammaCorrection,nlevels)
#compute(img[, winStride[, padding[, locations]]]) -> descriptors
winStride = (8,8)
padding = (8,8)
locations = ((10,20),)


out = []
for x in range(0,20):
    image = cv2.imread("{}.jpg".format(x),0)
    hist = hog.compute(image,winStride,padding,locations)
    #print (hist)
#print (len(hist))
#print (len(hist[0]))
    out.append(hist)
#   print ("***********")
np.savetxt('hog.txt',out)
```

Comment: What does this `hog.txt` look like?

Comment: Nothing is getting saved..

Comment: What is it supposed to look like?

Comment: It should contain feature vectors like this: f1 f2 f3......................f1564 for each image that is the size should be 20*1564.

Comment: Convert or map that data to string.

Comment: I changed the format to string but it didn't worked still getting the same error..

Comment: Are these feature vectors some objects? If yes, read their documentation for how to convert them to string for saving them as you cannot save Python objects directly using plain text. Btw you can use something like `pickle` module for storing objects as well!